# .NET Core app configuration: Specify INI file encoding

Tags: .net, .net-core, configuration, configuration-files

During startup of my app, I read configuration values from INI file:

```
configBuilder.AddIniFile("appsettings.ini");
```

However, encoding of `appsettings.ini` is different from UTF-8 (Windows-1250 in my case). Thus, there is a problem with all configuration values that contain diacritics.

Is there a way how to specify encoding of configuration file so that all configuration values are read properly?

(Changing encoding of `appsettings.ini` is not possible in my case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what works for me

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
var configText = File.ReadAllText("config2.ini", Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250"));
var ms = new MemoryStream();
ms.Write(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(configText));
ms.Position = 0;

IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .AddIniStream(ms)
              .Build();

ms.Dispose();
```

Comment: Good idea with `AddIniStream`! I did'nt know about this method...

Answer (score 0):

Using StreamReader may help, as you can specify an encoding when reading the file.  There are different encodings to choose from (UTF8, Unicode etc.).  .NET Core Console app example below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleDiacritic
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReadFile();
        }

        private static void ReadFile()
        {
            string sourceFile = @"c:\\temp\\appsettings.ini";

            using (var filestream = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, useAsync: true))
            {
                using var streamReader = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                Console.WriteLine(lines);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I am familiar with `StreamReader` however I cannot find the way how to utilize it in .NET Core configuration pipeline (=I want to add configuration file via `configBuilder.AddIniFile("appsettings.ini")`, not by manual file parsing.)

Comment: What's the encoding of your ini files?

Comment: Apologies: you state Windows 1250 encoding.